Bazel use select with condition on config_setting when compilation_mode is dbg/debug
I'd like to write a basic rule on adding some sources when configuration is on debug mode
cc_library(
    name = "mylib",
    strip_include_prefix = "/mylib/include/" ,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [  ":lib_headers",
           ] + 
            + select({
         "@config_setting//compilation_mode:dbg":  [":dbg_add_symb"] ,
          "//conditions:default" : [] ,
    }) 
    ,
    tags = ["manual"],
    linkstatic=1,
)

that way is clearly not understood by bazel , what is the true condition please?
which is the key target saying we are in debug mode compilation please ?
thank you
@hlopko @dms
bazel build :mylib
does not work as the condition
"@config_setting//compilation_mode:dbg":  [":dbg_add_symb"] ,
is note understood, I dont find what is the condition I should write.

Add
config_setting(
    name = "compilation_mode_dbg",
    values = {
        "compilation_mode": "dbg",
    },
)

and then you can do
select({
    ":compilation_mode_dbg": [":dbg_add_symb"],
    "//conditions:default": [],
})

See https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes

why bazel don't have such setting by default?

Probably because it never really came up often enough, and it's easy enough to add the config_setting where you need it. If bazel were to include one, it would be in the built-in @bazel_tools repository, and there's a general desire to reduce what's in there (and one day maybe eliminate it).

Thank you a lot for your answer and your light
I read the doc but i did not understand that will be a condition that will automatically be true without including it in the build command line.
